# linq fields using conditional criteria

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am new to VB.Net having come from an MS Access background.  I am working on a program that uses linq with a SQL back end.  There is a data context for Contacts.

Maybe this illustration will clarify.  This is what was handed off to me:

Contacts table:

```
ContactID (PK)
```

a_ContactTypes table:

```
ContactTypeID (PK)
ContactType
```

ContactTypes junction table:

```
ContactTypeID (PK)
aContactTypeID
ContactID
```

Let's say I have the following items in the `Contacts` table:

```
ContactID
---------
Contact1
Contact2
Contact3
```

And the following items in the a_`ContactTypes` table:

```
ContactTypeID   ContactType
-------------   -----------
Type1           Business
Type2           Private
```

And this is what the ContactTypes junction table looks like:

```
ContactTypeID   ContactID  aContactTypeID
-------------   ---------  --------------
1               Contact1   Type1
2               Contact1   Type2
3               Contact3   Type2
```

So `Contact1` has Contact Types `Private` and `Business`, `Contact2` has no Contact Types, and `Contact3` only has Contact Type `Private`.  (The `ContactTypeID` meaning two different things in the two tables is a bit confusing, but it is the lot I was handed and a minor inconvenience)

What I am able to get into a grid is the following with Linq:

```
Contact1   Business
Contact1   Private
Contact2   
Contact3   Private
```

What I want to get into a grid with Linq is:

```
ID         Business    Private
--------   --------    -------
Contact1   True        True
Contact2   False       False
Contact3   False       True
```

So do I simply create a bunch of Contact objects and use a for each loop to fill in the contact types or is there a nice, neat way of doing this within a linq query itself?

Disclaimer: I repeat that I am moving from a mainly MS Access VBA background, so my terminology (and overall knowledge) may be off.  I have searched, but nothing seemed to fit what I am trying to do, but I am probably searching without the correct terminology (and overall knowledge). I also tried to get the example into a list, but it does not look like I am applying the asterisk properly.

Comment: Use the code-button in the editor to format _code_ blocks. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Please at least make an effort to format your posts. The orange `{?}` button above the top right of the text area where you're entering it explains how to do so. Also, please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks. :-)

Comment: Thanks Ken -- I went in to do so and it told me you had already edited.  My apologies.

Comment: Can you post your current LINQ query?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code [(Sourced from here)](http://www.extensionmethod.net/csharp/ienumerable-t/pivot) and [converted](http://converter.telerik.com/).  You may be able to make use of it:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Namespace ReflectionIT.Training

    Public NotInheritable Class LinqExtenions
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub

        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
        Public Shared Function Pivot(Of TSource, TFirstKey, TSecondKey, TValue)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), firstKeySelector As Func(Of TSource, TFirstKey), secondKeySelector As Func(Of TSource, TSecondKey), aggregate As Func(Of IEnumerable(Of TSource), TValue)) As Dictionary(Of TFirstKey, Dictionary(Of TSecondKey, TValue))
            Dim retVal = New Dictionary(Of TFirstKey, Dictionary(Of TSecondKey, TValue))()

            Dim l = source.ToLookup(firstKeySelector)
            For Each item As var In l
                Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of TSecondKey, TValue)()
                retVal.Add(item.Key, dict)
                Dim subdict = item.ToLookup(secondKeySelector)
                For Each subitem As var In subdict
                    dict.Add(subitem.Key, aggregate(subitem))
                Next
            Next

            Return retVal
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Hi Monty.  This looks like just what the doctor ordered.  I have never used the Dictionary class, but I did some research and it looks like it should do exactly what I need.  I will try some code tomorrow and let you know how it goes.  Thank you so much for pointing me in this direction.